# Nodemailer Incorrect authentication data

Tags: email, nestjs, nodemailer

I am writing a function for sending magic links to new users.

```
 public async sendMagicLink(email: string) {
        const transporter = mailer.createTransport({
          host: 'smtp.ukr.net',
          port: 465,
          secure: true,
          auth: {
            user: 'myemail',
            pass: 'my password',
          },
        });
        transporter.verify().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
      }
```

And the code fails with this error.

```
  Error: Invalid login: 535 Incorrect authentication data
     at SMTPConnection._formatError
```

Credentials are 100% correct. Does anyone have any ideas about what might have gone wrong? I have tried all solutions possible both from stack overflow and github.

And if I set `port:2525` and `secure: false` I get `Error: Greeting never received` and `greetingTimeout` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed `type: 'LOGIN',` in auth, try it.